# Efficient Algorithm To Find A Path Which Covers Maximum Area Along Polygonal Perimeter For Surveillance Application

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, graphs, formal-languages, time-complexity

In the context of surveillance, I am working on a project where the goal is to find an algorithm that determines a path along a polygonal area, connecting a root node to a target node, while maximizing the surveillance area covered within the polygon. The given inputs for my algorithm include a root node, a target node, and the polygonal area representing the boundaries of the area to be monitored.

To clarify, the surveillance is to be done inside the polygonal area, and the path found can overlap. The important constraint is that the path should cover the maximum area of the polygon in the most optimal and efficient manner.

To tackle this problem, I have explored different approaches, including graph traversal algorithms like Dijkstra's algorithm and A* search. However, I haven't found a solution that directly addresses the requirement of maximizing the coverage area.

Considering the additional details, I believe that an algorithm that takes into account the distances between the polygon's points and the root and target nodes could be a potential solution. The algorithm should aim to find the shortest path that covers the maximum area within the polygon, ensuring that the path connects the root and target nodes effectively. The surveillance will be conducted inside the polygon, allowing for path overlap.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or guidance on how to approach this problem. If you could provide suggestions, pseudocode, or high-level explanations of potential algorithms, it would be immensely helpful in getting me started.

Comment: Generally a good way to specify an algorithm problem is to specify the inputs to the algorithm and the desired output.  It is not clear what kinds of paths are permissible (must it be a path along the polygon, or can it be along the interior?).  You will need to specify what is the surveillance area  covered by a path, as that is not described.  I encourage you to [edit] your post to incorporate this information.

Comment: I don't understand what area of the polygon is covered by a given path.  That isn't described.  I don't understand what is meant by "the path found can overlap".  I don't understand what it means to "cover the maximum area of the polygonal perimeter".  The perimeter is a 1D object so it has length, not area.  If you want to cover the maximum length, then your path should include all of the perimeter.  I don't understand what is meant by "in the most optimal and efficient manner".  Optimal has not been defined, and no metric has been defined for efficient.

Comment: A path is a line. A line covers no area. Your description is insufficient. By the way, there are only two paths *along a polygon* that join two given points, making the problem trivial.

Comment: Presumably you are in fact asking to draw a path *inside* the polygon, and such that it "sees" an area of a constant width on either sides. If this is the case, IMO a systematic scan with parallel lines will be close to optimal. The direction of the lines is unimportant, the path length will be close to the polygon area over the width.